# Postgresql Is it possible to create a selection based on a 'case value'

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to create a selection based on a 'case value'. In below example the `Category`. Let's say I want to get the `Low` value. It throws up a error when I use `WHERE Category  = 'Low'`, because the column `Category` does not exist.

I know I could create the selection by replacing `WHERE Category  = 'Low'` with `Where digit > 0 AND digit <=40`. But that seems like a bad way to do so  because off the double expression.

```
SELECT digits,

    CASE 
        When digit > 0 AND digit <=40 THEN 'Low'
        When digit > 40 AND digit <=75 THEN 'Average'
        When digit > 75  THEN 'High'
    END AS Category

FROM digits_table

WHERE Category  = 'Low'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a with statement:

```
WITH tmp as (
SELECT digits,

CASE 
    When digit > 0 AND digit <=40 THEN 'Low'
    When digit > 40 AND digit <=75 THEN 'Average'
    When digit > 75  THEN 'High'
END AS Category

FROM digits_table
)
select * from tmp where category = 'Low'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or (old skool):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT digits,
    CASE 
        When digit > 0 AND digit <=40 THEN 'Low'
        When digit > 40 AND digit <=75 THEN 'Average'
        When digit > 75  THEN 'High'
    END AS Category
    FROM digits_table
) AS tmp WHERE Category = 'Low'
```

Answer (score 1):

With PSQL 9.2+ you can use [Range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) and [Range functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html)

#### tl;dr;

`select * from digits_table where digits <@ int4range(0, 40, '(]');`

#### Long version

Consider this table:

```
postgres=# select * from tests;
 id | digit 
----+-------
  1 |    10
  2 |    20
  3 |    30
  4 |    40
```

You can query (*note that int4range bottom bound here is **inclusive**, whereas top bound is **exclusive***):

```
postgres=# select * from tests where digit <@ int4range(20,40);
 id | digit 
----+-------
  2 |    20
  3 |    30
```

Of course, you can cast a string to a desired in/exclusion mode (just put it down as you would normally do at math class, then cast to a range type):

```
postgres=# select * from tests where digit <@ '(20,40]'::int4range;
 id | digit 
----+-------
  3 |    30
  4 |    40

postgres=# select * from tests where digit <@ '[20,40]'::int4range;
 id | digit 
----+-------
  2 |    20
  3 |    30
  4 |    40
```

There is an easier yet explicit way to control bounds (this is PostgreSQL, baby!):

```
postgres=# select * from tests where digit <@ int4range(20,40,'[]');
 id | digit 
----+-------
  2 |    20
  3 |    30
  4 |    40

postgres=# select * from tests where digit <@ int4range(20,40,'()');
 id | digit 
----+-------
  3 |    30

postgres=# select * from tests where digit <@ int4range(20,40,'[)');
 id | digit 
----+-------
  2 |    20
  3 |    30
```